# Downloading of mnist data using Keras and Tensorflow

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I need to download Mnist data in order to work with it later. How can I do this? Should I have install Python on my device? I have tried to use such code and I receive an errors [first error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psIyX.png):

```
install.packages("tensorflow") 
library(tensorflow) 
#reticulate::install_miniconda()
install_tensorflow()

install.packages("keras") 
library(keras) 
install_keras()

mnist <- dataset_mnist()
X_train <- mnist$train$x
X_test <- mnist$test$x
y_train <- mnist$train$y
y_test <- mnist$test$y
```

[Second error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1u59d.png) How can I do this installation in a right way?

Comment: The "SSL in Conda on Windows" issue is patched in the master version of reticulate. Please try again after `remotes::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")`, and if you still encounter errors please file an issue on github.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused, if you have a problem downloading the dataset, you can use the following code:

```
#install.packages("dslabs")
library(dslabs)
mnist <- read_mnist()
```

Comment: I need actually keras or tensorlow

Answer (score 0):

First Approach

`#install.packages("dslabs")`

`library(dslabs)`

`mnist_db="C:/users/you/Downloads/MNIST"`

`mnist <- read_mnist(download = TRUE, destdir = mnist_db)`

`mnist <- read_mnist(destdir)`

Second Approach

`pip install get-mnist`

`mnist_folder="C:/users/mtalo/desktop/FREEUNIV/DATA/MNIST"`

`x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = mnist.mnist(mnist_folder)`